# Oracle APEX - Pie Chart not showing well on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am using 
- Oracle APEX 4.2.6
- Mozilla Firefox ESR **52.3.0 (32 bits)**

I've developed a Pie Chart that show some functional statistics. The issue is that the Pie chart did not show very well. In fact, it shows bad on the **Developement** environnement, but it shows well on the **Qualification** environnement:

Below a screenshot of the chart on the two environnement:

1- Developpement environnement

[image: Developpement environnement]

2 - Qualification environnement
[image: Qualification environnement]

What can be the problem with this issue?

NB: it's worked well on Chrome and IE browsers. But should work too on Firefox.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If it looks OK in the Qualification environment, maybe you should try to set the Development environment to be the same as the Q. one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that I have two different versions of AnyChart in both environnements and one of them is not compatible with the FireFox version 52.3.0.

The charts with AnyChart version **6.2.0** do not show as expected in the developpement environnement. But they show well in the qualificcation env with an old AnyChart version **6.0.11**

I contacted the AnyChart support, this is their last reply:

> Great, now I see. Thank you for your report!
>       In this case, we may suggest you using version 6.0.11 in both environments. 
>       Also, you can get AnyChart.js from the environment server where pie chart works properly and use this js in the other environment.
>       We will investigate this issue related to 6.2.0 version. 
>       As AnyChart is a part of Apex, please, contact Oracle support and report this issue.

To resolve the issue, I use the same AnyChart files of qualification env in the dev env: **AnyChart.js and AnyChartHTML5.js** files existed in the installation directory of APEX.

Answer (score 2):

I meet the same problem a year or two ago. My research shows that it is a bug in Firefox and/or AnyChart. I saw several topics on forums (including the official Oracle forum), everywhere this reason was mentioned.
Also, take a look at [this page](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2238674_1.html):

> Product Management investigated the issue and concluded that this is not an APEX code issue, but specific to AnyChart HTML5 charts. Hence they are internally coordinating with the AnyChart.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. Even if it's AnyChart issue, why it works on an environnement and do not work on an other? The two env are similars.

Comment: @O.Sam I am not an expert in web development. Can't say exactly, sorry. Maybe it is possible to find a solution in questions about AnyChart here or elsewhere in internet.

Comment: Thanks Dimitry, will see with AnyChart experts. I will share if I find something...